# Regularity of the boundary of a set difference

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

Let $\Omega_{1},\Omega_{2} \subset \mathbb{R^2}$ be open, connected and bounded domain with piecewise smooth boundary.

Let suppose that $\Omega_{1}\cap\Omega_{2}\neq \emptyset$ has a piecewise smooth boundary and a finite number of connected componets (like the intersection of two cirlces).

Can we say that $\Omega_{1} \setminus \overline{\Omega_{2}}$ has a piecewise smooth boundary ?

Should I look for some "transversality" conditions in this case ?

Comment: I think this is a consequence of the fact that:
$\partial(\Omega_{0}\setminus\overline{\Omega_{1}})=\left[\partial(\Omega_{0}\cap\Omega_{1})\cap\partial(\Omega_{0}\setminus\overline{\Omega_{1}})\right]\cup\left[\partial(\Omega_{0})\cap\partial(\Omega_{0}\setminus\overline{\Omega_{1}})\right]$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A domain $\Omega$ in $R^n$ has piecewise smooth boundary if for each $x\in cl(\Omega)$ there exists a neighborhood $U$ of $x$ in $R^n$ and a diffeomorphism $f: U\to U'\subset R^n$, such that $f(cl(\Omega))\cap U$ equals $\Omega'\cap U'$, where $\Omega'\subset R^n$ is a convex polyhedron.

Consider two shapes: a square, $\Omega_1$, that has its four corners located at the points $(0,-1), (2,-1), (2,1)$ and $(0,1)$ and a circle, $\Omega_2$, with a radius of 1 and its center at the origin as shown in the following image:

[image]

Notice that the point $A=(0,1),B=(0,-1)$ does not satisfy the cone properties.
So $\Omega_1 - \overline{\Omega_2}$ is not a domain with piecewise smooth boundary. This region contains "cups" or non-smooth points. Futhermore $\Omega_1 \cap {\Omega_2}$ has piecewise smooth boundary.

[image]